# 3D Projection (onto 2D) regarding attributes other than position, color

Tags: opengl, 3d, transformation, projection, mesh

basically it is the same thing OpenGL does. I want to project a 3D model to 2D plane where the 3D model has vertices and faces which have many attributes along with coordinates or colors.

Namely I need several 2D projections of color, attributes1, attibutes2....attibutesN from 3D Model. Of course not every 2D projection need to render as am image.

Can I use OpenGL to solve the problem? What I understand from OpenGL projection or any model-view-transformation is about coordinate transformation. I how can let other attributes also "projected" to the proper place on 2D plane?

a quick idea is encoding vertex/face attributes in color or texture, letting OpenGL project the 3D model onto 2D plane, and then decode the color or texture value from each pixel on 2D plane.

Or is there any better solution which can be implemented without OpenGL trick?

thanks

Comment: What kind of attributes are you talking about?  Are they floats?  How should those attributes be handled in between vertices?  Interpolation the same way as with colors?

Comment: @JCopper: some attributes like material reflection property or other physical properties. They are indeed float type. I would like to let those attributes just interpolated as color, but it would be great if I can setup some weighting function. And I don't really need to render those attributes into draw-able images, I would rather want to directly get a 2d array (like an image) of projected/interpolated attribute values.

Answer (score 2):

Let V be the n-vector of n attributes you want to project, and M the (n+1)×m projection matrix, then M V is your projection. It's really that simple. What really matters, is finding a projection from n-space to 2-space that makes sense.

Comment: not really. I want to project 3D scene onto a 2D plane regarding the geometry transformation, just like OpenGL does. But I need to also project/render some attributes other than just color or texture.

Comment: I fully understand this, you can transform those additional attributes by this matrix, too. You must understand, that those additional attributes are just additional elements of the vertex vector and are thus also transformed. It would help if you specified how and into what those additional attributes shall be transformed.